# Imagemagick overlay two texts ontop of eachother ontop of image?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am trying to overlay two texts (one is larger and and a different color, which would end up being the stroke) ontop of an image, but what I get ends up being a messed up result.

I am using

```
convert front2.jpg 
\( -pointsize 90 -font Helvetica-Narrow-Bold -fill black -background none -stroke black -strokewidth 15 label:"Hello World World" -virtual-pixel transparent -distort arc 160 \) -gravity north -geometry +0+12 -compose over -composite front5.jpg 
\( -pointsize 90 -font Helvetica-Narrow-Bold -fill white -stroke none -background none label:"Hello World World" -virtual-pixel transparent -distort arc 160 \) -gravity north -geometry +0+10 -compose over -composite front5.jpg
```

How can I do this and get the right result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just realised I missread your post; these examples will create a drop shadow effect. Whatever I try I can not get -stroke to work!
UPDATE - stroke will work but not on my local setup; the last example has stroke.

This works for me but is quite slow:

```
exec("convert image.jpg -thumbnail 800x800 temp.png");

$cmd = " temp.png \( -pointsize 90 -font Helvetica-Narrow-Bold -fill black -background none label:\"Hello World World\" -virtual-pixel transparent -distort arc 160 \) ".
" -gravity north -geometry +0+12 -compose over -composite  ".
" \( -pointsize 90 -font Helvetica-Narrow-Bold -fill white -background none label:\"Hello World World\" -virtual-pixel transparent -distort arc 160 \) ".
" -gravity north -geometry +0+10 -composite ";

exec("convert $cmd text_circle.png");
```

This is completed in half the time but has a problem that the text is larger than the image! Doing some calculations to reduce $size[0] and $size[1] would overcome that.

```
$size = getimagesize("temp.png");
$cmd = " temp.png \( \( -size $size[0]x$size[1] xc:none -fill black -font Helvetica-Narrow-Bold -pointsize 90 -stroke black -strokewidth 4 -gravity north -annotate +0+0 \"Hello World World\" -font Helvetica-Narrow-Bold -fill white -annotate +3+3 \"Hello World World\" \) -virtual-pixel transparent -distort arc 160 \) ".
" -composite ";
exec("convert $cmd text_circle1.png");
```